# How to get route parameters from a url in angular2 app?

Tags: angular

I have a constant ROUTES that is set up like this:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'custom', component: MyCustomComponent }
]
```

I want to make it so that if the user goes to:

```
http://my-angular-app/#/custom/something?mode=CRAZY
```

That within "MyCustomComponent", I can see access the "mode=CRAZY" and do something with it.

How do I access the variable "mode" from my MyCustomComponent? Or do I have to define a new route to be able to pass the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what works for me to access the query parameters within a component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom.component.css']
})
export class CustomComponent {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    let mode = activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['mode']; //< HERE
    console.log(mode);
  }    
}
```

You need to import the `ActivatedRoute`, and inject it via the constructor. Then you can access what comes in on the query string via the injected service.

With a router link like this:

`<a [routerLink]="['/custom']" [queryParams]="{mode: 'CRAZY'}">Go There!</a>`

The output from the console log is `CRAZY`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want the mode: CRAZY to be "bookmarkable" in the browser. I assume queryParams passes it into the route as post?

Comment: Since you are using hashes in the URL, you should be able to bookmark these. The server ignores anything after the hash. `queryParams` passes information on the URL, so that is a GET, not a POST.

Answer (score 2):

As said in other answer, you may use `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParam` but if your queryParam change it's value while you are in the same route you'll have problems if you need to update the value that you got from the queryParam. As you are in the same route angular won't recreate the component for, so you won't get the new value from the snapshot in your constructor. If you need to get the updated value while in the same route, you should subscribe to que queryParam observable.

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams) => {
    console.log(queryParams); // get the values of your queryParams
  });
}
```

Now, every new value on your queryParams will be updated in your Component. And as it is an Angular Observable you won't be bother to treat it's unsubscription manually, Angular'll take care of it for you.